# Download 50 twitch.tv clips for a specific game for the past week

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests, twitch

I'm using the code beneath to list 50 twitch.tv clips from the past 7 days. For some reason, the script isn't getting the top viewed clip and is starting further down. (*see images*)

```
import requests

url = "https://gql.twitch.tv/gql"
json_req = """[{"query":"query ClipsCards__Game($gameName: String!, $limit: Int, $cursor: Cursor, $criteria: GameClipsInput) { game(name: $gameName) { id clips(first: $limit, after: $cursor, criteria: $criteria) { pageInfo { hasNextPage __typename } edges { cursor node { id slug url embedURL title viewCount language curator { id login displayName __typename } game { id name boxArtURL(width: 52, height: 72) __typename } broadcaster { id login displayName __typename } thumbnailURL createdAt durationSeconds __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } } ","variables":{"gameName":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","limit":50,"criteria":{"languages":[],"filter":"LAST_WEEK"},"cursor":"MjA="},"operationName":"ClipsCards__Game"}]"""
r = requests.post(url, data=json_req, headers={"client-id":"kimne78kx3ncx6brgo4mv6wki5h1ko"})
r_json = r.json()

edges = r_json[0]['data']['game']['clips']['edges']
urls = [edge['node']['url'] for edge in edges]

for url in urls:
    print (url)
```

I'm trying to get the top 50 clips, starting from the most viewed and on. When scrolling down to invoke more clips to be shown, the first clip to load is the first clip to be stored instead of the actual first top clip.

- First clip (desired clip to be saved and so on..)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g4R1.jpg
- Clip that is stored
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiKJR.jpg

For any more information, please do ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-clips) I don't see that the data returned is in any particular order.

Testing your code I did find the top clip in the list, you probably have to sort by view count to get the same result than on the pages you showed.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm not entirely how I'd go about achieving the above.

Comment: Each node represents a clip. You managed to extract the url correctly. But if you were only to extract nodes (i.e. `[edge['node'] for edge in edges]`) then you will have access to 'view_count' as well as the 'url' for each clip/node. You just need to first sort that list by 'view_count' and then print out the urls.

Comment: ordering by viewcount doesn't resolve this case. I am still retrieving the JSON starting from when the second page of clips is generated (if that makes sense).

Comment: I might've misunderstood something then. If I take the url of the first clip I saw it in the last your script generated. Just not in the first box of the array. Is that also the case for you?

Comment: I'e managed to fix this issue, thank you for your help anyway.